# 'Arithmetic overflow error converting int to data type numeric' error on my Query

Tags: sql-server, stored-procedures

Whats wrong with my logic query? i just want to calculate users rating

```
UPDATE MyTable
        SET RatingAvg = CASE
                        WHEN RatingAvg = 0 THEN @Rating
                        ELSE CAST(((( CAST(RatingAvg AS DECIMAL(7,6)) * CAST(ReviewCount AS DECIMAL(7,6))) + CAST(@Rating AS DECIMAL(7,6))) / CAST((ReviewCount + 1)AS DECIMAL(7,6))) AS DECIMAL(7,6))
                        END
```

Comment: please add sample data

Comment: What is datatype of `@Rating`?

Comment: This is a great place to start: [How to post a T-SQL question on a public forum](http://spaghettidba.com/2015/04/24/how-to-post-a-t-sql-question-on-a-public-forum/)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It seems the error occurs when you cast big int to `decimal(7,6)`

Decimal defines the TOTAL number of digits, and then the number after the decimal. So in this case the max number is `9` that you can cast to  `decimal(7,6)`

When you try cast the number greater than 9 to `decimal(7,6)` then you will get an error

> Arithmetic overflow error converting int to data type numeric.